# Is moving wp-config outside the web root really beneficial?

Tags: security, customization, wp-config

One of the most common security best practices these days seems to be [moving `wp-config.php` one directory higher than the vhost's document root](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-config.php). I've never really found a good explanation for that, but I'm assuming it's to minimize the risk of a  malicious or infected script within the webroot from reading the database password.

But, you still have to let WordPress access it, so you need to expand `open_basedir` to include the directory above the document root. Doesn't that just defeat the entire purpose, and also potentially expose server logs, backups, etc to attackers?

Or is the technique only trying to prevent a situation where `wp-config.php` would be shown as plain-text to anyone requesting `http://example.com/wp-config.php`, instead of being parsed by the PHP engine? That seems like a very rare occurance, and it wouldn't outweigh the downsides of exposing logs/backups/etc to HTTP requests.

Maybe it's possible to move it outside the document root in some hosting setups without exposing other files, but not in other setups?

---

**Conclusion:** 
After a lot of back-and-forth on this issue, two answers have emerged that I think should be considered the authoritative ones. Aaron Adams makes a good case in [favor of moving](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/is-moving-wp-config-outside-the-web-root-really-beneficial#answer-74972) wp-config, and chrisguitarguymakes a good [case against it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/is-moving-wp-config-outside-the-web-root-really-beneficial#answer-58820). Those are the two answers you should read if you're new to the thread and don't want to read the entire thing. The other answers are either redundant or inaccurate.

Comment: It's really not necessary to plug your choice of answers and reject all other answers, inside your question.  As you can see below, that's what the stackexchange voting system is for, to vote up the answers that make sense to people, whereas the question askers should be using the "accepted answer" mechanism and your own up/down votes.

Comment: I don't do that for 99% of the questions I've asked, but I thought it was appropriate in this specific case. There are 8 answers to the question, some of which are fairly lengthly/complex, and some of which have a lot of upvotes despite despite containing inaccurate info or not adding anything to the conversation. I think offering a semi-authoritative conclusion is helpful to people reading the thread for the first time. As always, readers are free to make up their own mind; I'm just offering my opinion as the OP.

Comment: @Kzqai: The "stackexchange voting system" is a democratic process, and the participants are often 1) unclear as to what the OP is actually asking or trying to solve, and 2) uncomprehending of any particular answer's validity. After the responses have trickled in and the votes have been cast, it is **more than helpful** to have the OP clarify those responses that provided assistance. After all, the OP is the only one who knows, and I wish more OPs did so. Yes, people "vote up the answers that make sense to people," but let's let the OP have the last word as to what makes sense to him.

Comment: Your question is a good one. However, your comments on the answers show that you have a very specific setup in mind with very real external (i.e. not controlled by you) constraints. It would have been fairer to state those up front. It makes a difference if I am in full control of the web server and PHP as well as systemd, say, or whether open_basedir is my only way of affecting security in a tangible way. Also: the "good case against" should point out how it is harmful, rather than listing reasons of why this singular measure may not be sufficient. And mind the audience.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

## Short answer: yes

The answer to this question is **yes** and to say otherwise is **probably irresponsible**.

---

## Long answer: a real-world example

Allow me to provide a very real example, from my very real server, where moving `wp-config.php` outside the web root **specifically prevented its contents from being captured**.

### The bug:

Take a look at this description of a bug in Plesk (fixed in 11.0.9 MU#27):

> [Plesk resets subdomain forwarding after syncing subscription with hosting plan (117199)](http://kb.parallels.com/en/115179)

Sounds harmless, right?

Well, here's what I did to trigger this bug:

1. Set up a subdomain to redirect to another URL (e.g. `site.staging.server.com` to `site-staging.ssl.server.com`).
2. Changed the subscription's service plan (e.g. its PHP configuration).

When I did this, Plesk reset the subdomain to defaults: serving the contents of `~/httpdocs/`, with no interpreters (e.g. PHP) active.

And I didn't notice. For weeks.

### The result:

- With `wp-config.php` in the web root, a request to `/wp-config.php` would have downloaded the WordPress configuration file.
- With `wp-config.php` outside the web root, a request to `/wp-config.php` downloaded a completely harmless file. The real `wp-config.php` file could not be downloaded.

Thus, it's obvious that moving `wp-config.php` outside the web root can have **bona fide security benefits in the real world**.

---

## How to move `wp-config.php` to any location on your server

WordPress will automatically look one directory above your WordPress installation for your `wp-config.php` file, so if that's where you've moved it, you're done!

But what if you've moved it somewhere else? Easy. Create a new `wp-config.php` in the WordPress directory with the following code:

```
<?php

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Location of your WordPress configuration. */
require_once(ABSPATH . '../phpdocs/wp-config.php');
```

(Be sure to change the above path to the actual path of your relocated `wp-config.php` file.)

If you run into a problem with `open_basedir`, just add the new path to the `open_basedir` directive in your PHP configuration:

```
open_basedir = "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/;/var/www/vhosts/example.com/phpdocs/;/tmp/"
```

That's it!

---

## Addressing arguments to the contrary

Every argument against moving `wp-config.php` outside the web root seems to hinge on false assumptions.

### Argument 1: If PHP is disabled, they're already in

> The only way someone is going to see that contents of
>   [`wp-config.php`] is if they circumvent your servers PHP interpreter…
>   If that happens, you're already in trouble: they have direct access to
>   your server.

**FALSE**: The scenario I describe above is the result of a misconfiguration, not an intrusion.

### Argument 2: Accidentally disabling PHP is rare, and therefore insignificant

> If an attacker has enough access to change the PHP handler, you're
>   already screwed. Accidental changes are very rare in my experience,
>   and in that case it'd be easy to change the password.

**FALSE**: The scenario I describe above is the result of a bug in a common piece of server software, affecting a common server configuration. This is hardly "rare" (and besides, security means worrying about the rare scenario).

Changing the password after an intrusion hardly helps if sensitive information was picked up during the intrusion. Really, do we still think WordPress is only used for casual blogging, and that attackers are only interested in defacement? Let's worry about protecting our server, not just restoring it after somebody gets in.

### Argument 3: Denying access to `wp-config.php` is good enough

> You can restrict access to the file via your virtual host config or
>   `.htaccess` – effectively limiting outside access to the file in the
>   same way that moving outside the document root would.

**FALSE**: Imagine your server defaults for a virtual host are: no PHP, no `.htaccess`, `allow from all` (hardly unusual in a production environment). If your configuration is somehow reset during a routine operation – like, say, a panel update – everything will revert to its default state, and you're exposed.

**If your security model fails when settings are accidentally reset to defaults, you probably need more security.**

Why would anybody specifically recommend fewer layers of security? Expensive cars don't just have locks; they also have alarms, immobilizers, and GPS trackers. If something's worth protecting, do it right.

### Argument 4: Unauthorized access to `wp-config.php` is no big deal

> The database information is really the only sensitive stuff in
>   [`wp-config.php`].

**FALSE**: The authentication keys and salts can be used in any number of potential hijacking attacks.

Even if database credentials were the only thing in `wp-config.php`, you should be *terrified* of an attacker getting their hands on them.

### Argument 5: Moving `wp-config.php` outside the web root actually makes a server *less* secure

> You still have to let WordPress access [`wp-config.php`], so you need
>   to expand `open_basedir` to include the directory above the document
>   root.

**FALSE**: Assuming `wp-config.php` is in `httpdocs/`, just move it to `../phpdocs/`, and set `open_basedir` to include only `httpdocs/` and `phpdocs/`. For instance:

```
open_basedir = "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/;/var/www/vhosts/example.com/phpdocs/;/tmp/"
```

(Remember to always include `/tmp/`, or your user `tmp/` directory, if you have one.)

---

## Conclusion: configuration files should always always *always* be located outside the web root

If you care about security, you should move `wp-config.php` outside your web root.

Comment: If you have a bug in apache, linux or the brain of the admin you are a toast in any case. In your scenario you fail to explain why it is more probable for a misconfiguration to happen at the root of the web site then in any other place on the server. A misconfigured apache can probably access /../config.php as easy as /config.php

Comment: You are not "toast in any case." It is _very probable_, and even _demonstrable_, that a bug would result in the web root being reset to its default, in which case you are not "toast" – your `wp-config.php` remains safe. And it is _extremely improbable_ – so much so as to essentially be impossible – that a bug would result in the web root being arbitrarily reset to the exact directory in which you placed your `wp-config.php`.

Comment: How probable this kind of bug is? I'm not a security expert but I never heard of such attack vector being used in practice. I'm, against recommending this method because once you need to maintain your site you don't know where your wp-config is and it will probably void most of the tutorials which touch that file in some way. You, me and the rest of the commenters here will figure what happened but for less experienced people it will be a big and long WTF moment.

Comment: @MarkKaplun "People who don't read Stack Exchange might get confused" is a pretty poor argument against a security practice being recommended _on Stack Exchange_. When more people understand the very real dangers of leaving sensitive configuration files inside the web root, more people will move those files outside the web root, and more WordPress tutorials will be written to help the user locate `wp-config.php`. If you think convenience is more important than security, that's your opinion; just make it clear, then, that you're recommending users prioritize convenience over security.

Comment: Hey Aaron, thanks for the thoughtful and detailed answer. You're right that just changing the pw after an intrusion isn't enough. I'm still not convinced by your Plesk anecdote, though. That's definitely a problem, but I don't think moving wp-config is the appropriate solution to that problem. Same for vhost config being reset, etc. If your app needs enough security that you're worried about those kinds of vulnerabilities, then you really need to address those in a more direct way. e.g,. don't use Plesk, because it'll always be vulnerable; make sure your vhost config is secure by default...

Comment: ...use configuration management to document and automatically enforce all aspects of the system, etc. One could argue that moving wp-config is a poor-man's alternative to more professional techniques, and that's fine, but I don't think it should be presented as a proper solution. In response to moving it httpdocs/../phpdocs, AFAIK, WordPress will only look for it one directory above ABSPATH, so that's not possible.

Comment: @IanDunn Actually, it's easy to move `wp-config.php` to an arbitrary location. I've added directions to my answer; it just involves creating a dummy `wp-config.php` in the WordPress directory referencing the location of the real one.

Comment: This response is spot-on. My web hosting company had a drive array failure.  When all was said & done they restored the system PARTIALLY.  Turns out they used a series of cPanel/WHM  scripts to rebuild httpd.conf files that did so incorrectly.  Luckily I already had wp-config.php outside of the doc root, but if I hadn't the contents were there for the taking. Yes rare, but as noted the rare cases are what you need to worry about.  Also, stating "simple minded folk would be lost" is a bad excuse for having LESS security.

Comment: That's a good point, Aaron. I'm still a little skeptical for the reasons I've mentioned in this and other comment thread, but you've convinced me that it has more merit than I originally thought. At the very least, if done properly, I don't think it will hurt anything. I still have a problem with the fact that most people promoting it don't seem to understand the reasons for it, and the way they teach it would often lead to the directory above httpdocs being exposed, but you've helped address those issues in your answer.

Comment: @IanDunn I completely agree with you that most people who recommend moving `wp-config.php` up a directory don't actually understand server security. They're the same people who would just as quickly recommend `chmod 777` on `.htaccess`, a file that could easily be used to redirect users to phishing sites. To be honest, this seems representative of the state of the WordPress community at large; there is a _stunning_ quantity of bad code out there, and due to the size of the community, it proliferates. All we can do is try to better educate people about the risks.

Comment: @CharlestonSoftwareAssociates I'm glad to hear you were well-prepared! To further protect myself against problems like this, I no longer allow files to sit in their default directories, either; those very Web files that were exposed just days ago in `~/httpdocs/` now reside in `~/sites/example.com/www/`. The next time something resets to defaults, domains will throw 500 errors, rather than serving up my PHP files raw.

Comment: @AaronAdams - that is a good idea, but in my case would not have helped.  They restored ENOUGH of the config to point it to my non-default doc root but not enough for it to work properly.  Really the worst possible scenario.  In fact SOME of the site worked after the 2nd attempt to fix it, but it was still not right.  Truly a horrible situation courtesy of a mis-managed server repair from my hosting company, which I feel underscores your point.   The more you can do to protect sensitive data even for that "once in a million" events, the better.

Comment: Can i write ../../wp-config.php or even different name? I just tried on one automator system with constant config beeing 1 level up. I just made that blog to be in subfolder therefore wanted to make wp-config.php 2 levels up but website didnt worked when using ../../ wich as ..// works while WP not in subfolder.

Comment: Very clear answer with a very clear conclusion. I've been practicing this and other security measures for years and had no security incidents on three separately hosted WordPress instances. I think the mere assumption that because something isn't _as effective_ alone as it is in combination with other measures. Yet people keep perpetuating this awkward advice to have SSH listen to unprivileged ("high") ports out of some false sense for security, for example. Either we deem security the result of a combination of measures aiming for it, or we leave it be altogether.

Comment: I messed up some config on nginx and it started to download files containing every sensitive information. So its definitely better to put wp-conf on directory up. Famous PHP framework "Laravel" uses same approach by default as well.

Comment: Minor question about the php-code: Is it beneficial to leave `?>` away in this special case? Or just personal preference?

Answer (score 44):

The biggest thing is the `wp-config.php` contains some sensitive information: your database username/password, etc.

So the idea: move it outside the document root, and you don't have to worry about anything. An attacker will never be able to access that file from an external source.

Here's the rub, however: `wp-config.php` never actually prints anything to the screen.  It only defines various constants that are used throughout your WP install.  Thus the only way someone is going to see that contents of that file is if they circumvent your servers PHP interpreter -- they get `.php` file to render as just plain text.  If that happens, you're already in trouble: they have direct access to your server (and probably root permissions) and can do whatever they like.

I'm going to go ahead and say **there's no benefit to moving `wp-config` outside the document root from a security perspective** -- for the reasons above and these:

1. You can restrict access to the file via your virtual host config or .htaccess -- effectively limiting outside access to the file in the same way that moving outside the document root would
2. You can ensure the file permissions are strict on `wp-config` to prevent any user without sufficient privileges from reading the file even if they gain (limited) access to your server via SSH.
3. Your sensitive information, database settings, are only used on a single site. So even if an attacker gained access to that information, the only site it would affect would be the WordPress install to which the `wp-config.php` file belongs.  More importantly, that database user only has permissions to read and write to that WP install's database and and nothing else -- no access to grant other users permissions.  Meaning, in otherwords, if an attacker gains access to your database, it's simply a matter of restoring from a backup (see point 4) and changing the database user
4. You backup often.  Often being a relative term: if you post 20 article every day, you better back up every day or every few days.  If you post once a week, backing up once a week is likely sufficient.
5. You have your site under version control ([like this](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton)), which means even if an attacker gained access, you can easily detect code changes and roll them back.  If an attacker has access to `wp-config`, they've probably messed with something else.
6. The database information is really the only sensitive stuff in `wp-config`, and because you're careful about it (see point 3 and 4), it's not a huge deal. Salts and such can be changed any time. The only thing that happens is that it invalidates logged in users' cookies.

To me, moving `wp-config` out of the document root reeks of security by obscurity -- which is very much a straw man.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I've been thinking. I'm glad to know I'm not the only one :)  I'd like to leave the question open for another day or two just in case somebody has a compelling counter-argument, but so far this seems like the right answer to me.

Comment: Minor correction: There's no *security* benefit to moving the wp-config.php file out of the document root. There are other benefits, which are not security related, and which only apply to unusual setups.

Comment: Good call.  Edited.

Comment: Just to get a possible myth debunked - is it not possible, something might go wrong server side - in which case php code is printed to the screen?

Comment: Sure.  If mod_php wasn't working or PHP files don't get passed to the PHP interpreter, it's possible.  If you're running a FCGI set up, the same thing is possible if PHP files don't get handed off to the fcgi process for interpretation. Both of those point to some pretty large issues that aren't likely to happen, however.

Comment: I think the core question here isn't whether or not there's some benefit to moving it, but whether or not those benefits outweigh the risk of expanding the openbase_dir scope to include the parent directory, which often contains log files, backups, a private file storage directory, etc. I keep asking about that, and none of the proponents of moving wp-config have ever given me an answer. So, at this point I'm taking their silence to mean that the benefits aren't worth the risk.

Comment: @IanDunn But the best answers advocate moving it out of that hierarchy altogether into a separate one, which does address your concern about logs etc. This answer doesn't answer your question title "is moving ... really beneficial", it just says other security measures are beneficial, and tries to reassure you into not worrying about security. Everyone thinks their house is secure until they get burgled. After that they do a better job. Some people never get burgled, even though their security is low, but it doesn't mean it's good advice to have lower security.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to move it anywhere except one directory above ABSPATH, because that's the only location WP will search for it.

Comment: Nevermind, Aaron updated his answer with a workaround for that, by using a dummy wp-config.php file to include() the real one.

Comment: These are good points, but my biggest problem with these is that they're remedial arguments, not preventative arguments. Most of these talk about how it's not a huge deal because A) you assume someone handled the db user correctly and B) you have backups. What happens when you're using something like woocommerce or storing sensitive information in your database? Then you're screwed.

Comment: I messed up some config on nginx and it started to download files containing every sensitive information. So its definitely better to put wp-conf on directory up. Famous PHP framework "Laravel" uses same approach by default as well.

Comment: What an ignorant take on security. As if there is no difference in scope between (accidentally) misconfiguring PHP and leaking credentials to the DB server and salts to the password hashes contained therein. While the eventual breaking point of security measures is binary, their implementation is not. Following your logic you can remove any building block, e.g. SELinux/AppArmor, without affecting overall system security. It should be obvious how wrong this is. Typically preemptive security measures attempt to guard even against the unlikely cases.

Answer (score 26):

I think Max's is a knowledgeable answer, and that's one side of the story. The [WordPress Codex has more advise](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress):

> Also, make sure that only you (and the web server) can read this file
>   (it generally means a 400 or 440 permission).
>
> If you use a server with .htaccess, you can put this in that file (at
>   the very top) to deny access to anyone surfing for it:
>
> ```
> <files wp-config.php>
> order allow,deny
> deny from all
> </files>
> ```

Note that setting 400 or 440 permission on wp-config.php may prevent plugins from writing to or modifying it. A genuine case for example would be, caching plugins (W3 Total Cache, WP Super Cache, etc.) In that case, I'd go with 600 (the default permission for files in `/home/user` directory).

Comment: Max's is the answer. +1 to him. I am simply trying to extend it.

Comment: Aahan Krish, you've hit the bull's eye. Thanks for the addition.

Comment: So if you use htaccess to deny HTTP requests to wp-config.php, doesn't that achieve the same result as moving it outside the document root, but without exposing logs/backups/etc?

Comment: @IanDunn Depends on what the document root is— **(1)** If wordpress is hosted in a directory in `public_html`, moving `wp-config.php` outside the directory means that it's going to be in `public_html` directory. In this case, you'll have to use the htaccess rules to deny HTTP requests to wp-config.php. **(2)** If WordPress is installed directly under `public_html` directory, one level up => you'll be moving it into `/home/user` directory. In this case you are pretty safe as the file is outside the document root. You can still set the file's permissions to 600 (or even stricter 440 or 400).

Comment: @IanDunn Like I said, this is my basic understanding, and I am no security expert. :)

Comment: In case #1 you don't get the intended security benefit. The whole point is to move it outside the document root, not just up one level.

Comment: In case #2, you'd have to expand the `open_basedir` scope to let PHP access everything in /home/user, which seems like a huge problem to me. Anything stored there (logs, backups, .bash_history, etc) would be accessible to any infected PHP script running in /home/user/public_html. It seems like it'd be better to leave wp-config at /home/user/public_html/wp-config.php and use htaccess rules to block HTTP requests to it. You still get the benefit of blocking access in the (unlikely) event that it's displayed in plain-text, but you don't expose files above public_html.

Answer (score 18):

Someone asked us to shine in, and I will reply here.

Yes, there are security benefits from isolating your wp-config.php from the root directory of your site.

1- If your PHP handler gets broken or modified in some way, your DB information will not be exposed. And yes, I saw this happen a few times on shared hosts during server updates. Yes, the site will be broken during that period, but your passwords will be intact.

2- Best practices always recommend isolating configuration files from data files. Yes, it is hard to do that with WordPress (or any web app), but moving it up does a bit of isolation.

3- Remember the PHP-CGI vulnerability, where anyone could pass the ?-s to a file and view the source. http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/520827

At the end, those are small details, but they do help to minimize risk. Specially if you are on a shared environment, where anyone can access your database (all they need is a user/pass).

But don't let small distractions (premature optimizations) get in front of what is really necessary to get a site properly secure:

1- Keep it always updated

2- Use strong passwords

3- Restrict access (via permissions). We have a post about it here:

http://blog.sucuri.net/2012/08/wordpress-security-cutting-through-the-bs.html

thanks,

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for adding your thoughts. I think we already hits on most of those points in the other answers and their comments. 1) Yes, this is possible, but rare; 2) Yes, this has benefits, but they're minimal; 3) Yes, this is possible, but that type of vulnerability is unlikely to happen again, and protecting against it is kind of like playing whac-a-mole, or making people remove their shoes at airports because some jackass hid a bomb in his shoe once. It's reactionary and unlikely to have future benefits.

Comment: In the various discussions, the question was refined from "Are there any benefits?" to "Ok, there are some benefits, but do they outweigh the risks?" The main risk I'm referring to is the fact that you have to expand the openbase_dir scope in order to let PHP access scripts outside the web root. Many hosting setups -- including those that use Plesk, which is a lot -- store logs, backups, private FTP areas that are supposed to be isolated from the web root, etc in the directory above the web root. So, giving PHP access to that directory can be a serious vulnerability.

Comment: @IanDunn since when has rarity of an event been a valid counterargument to taking a preemptive security measure addressing such unlikely event? Your point about where PHP can open files can these days be addressed via systemd hardening, btw. The whole point in IT security is that attackers have infinitely many routes of incursion at their disposal, whereas defenders can only ever defend against known attack vectors. Thus it is customary to combine as many preventative measures as feasible to provide a security net, rather than relying on a single knot.

Answer (score 16):

Definitely YES.

When you move *wp-config.php* outside public directory you protect it from reading using browser when php handler gets maliciously (or accidentally!) changed.

Reading your DB login/password is possible when server is hardly infected through a fault of lame administrator. Charge the administrator a fine and get a better-tended and more reliable server host. Though that may be more expensive.

Comment: If an attacker has enough access to change the PHP handler, you're already screwed. Accidental changes are very rare in my experience, and in that case it'd be easy to change the password. In light of those things, do you still think it's worth the risk of exposing logs/backups/etc because of the expanded `open_basedir` scope?

Comment: I've never had `-rwx` access to directories higher than `public_html` so I never was familiar with `open_basedir`. My logs are in separate directory, so backups do. I think that's what all shared hosts have.

Comment: Hosts vary wildly; there's no standard directory structure. Plesk (one of the most popular control panels for shared hosts) puts logs in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs and the document root is /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs. Moving wp-config.php to /var/www/vhosts/example.com/wp-config.php would require giving scripts access to the entire example.com directory.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where are your logs and backups stored, if not in the domain's directory? Are they accessed through a control panel or something?

Comment: Yes, through a control panel.

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but if your server is not secure, a symlink attack could read your wp-config.php regardless of where it is. All an attacker has to know is where the file could possibly be and if symlinking is possible. This maybe an off topic question, but it would seem if there was a way to rename the wp-config.php, that would be a way to prevent phishing for it.

Comment: The filename `wp-config.php` is hardcoded into `wp-load.php`, so changing it isn't possible without modifying core.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to clarify, for the sake of argument, that moving your wp_config.php file does not necessarily mean you have to move it only to the parent directory. Let's say you have a structure like /root/html, where html contains the WP installation and all of your HTML content. Instead of moving wp_config.php to /root, you could move it to something like /root/secure ... which is both outside the html directory and also not in the server root directory. Of course, you would need to make sure that php can run in this secure folder as well.

Since WP cannot be configured to look for wp_config.php in a sibling folder like /root/secure, you have to take an additional step. I left the wp_config.php in /root/html, and cut out the sensitive portions (database login, salt, table prefix) and moved them to a separate file called config.php. Then you add the PHP `include` command to your wp_config.php, like this: `include('/home/content/path/to/root/secure/config.php');`

This is essentially what I've done in my setup. Now, based on the above discussion, I am still evaluating whether it is necessary or even a good idea. But I just wanted to add that the above configuration is possible. It does not expose your backups and other root files, and so long as the secure folder is not set up with its own public URL, it is not browsable.

Furthermore, you can limit access to the secure folder by creating an .htaccess file in there with:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for sharing that. Have you tried it out in a real environment to verify it works, though? I think the `open_basedir` directive takes an entire *tree*, so in order to access `/root/secure` from `/root/html`, you'd have to set `open_basedir` to `/root`.

Comment: In order to make your idea work, I think you'd need to setup the directory structure like `/root/httpdocs/config/accessible`, where `httpdocs` holds logs, backups, etc; `config` holds `wp-config.php`, and `accessible` holds WordPress and all content. You'd have to modify the vhost config, etc to remap the document root to `accessible`. I don't see any benefit over just denying HTTP requests to wp-config in the default setup, though.

Comment: According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir: "Under Windows, separate the directories with a semicolon. On all other systems, separate the directories with a colon. As an Apache module, open_basedir paths from parent directories are now automatically inherited." So you can set multiple directories, no need for them to be in a single tree.

Comment: I just tested that out and it looks like you're right. I'm still not sure what security benefit this has over simply denying access to the file via Apache, though.

Comment: @IanDunn addressed well in Aaron Adams' answer

Comment: I don't find his argument for that convincing. I've explained why in my comment on his answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of bad written themes and plugins out there which allow atatckers to inject code (remember the security issue with Timthumb). If I would be a attacker, why should I search for the wp-config.php? Simply inject this code:

```
var_dump( DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD );
```

You can try to hide your wp-config.php. As long as WordPress make all the sensitive information global accessible, it have no benefit to hide the wp-config.php.

The bad part in wp-config.php is not that it holds sensitive data. The bad part is to define the sensitive data as a global accessible constant.

**Update**

I want to clearify the problems with `define()` and why it is a bad idea to define sensitive data as a global constant.

There are a lot of ways to attack a website. Script injection is only one way to atack a website.

Assuming the server has a vulnerability that let an attacker access a memory dump.
The attacker will find in the memory dump all values of all variables. If you define a global accessible constant, it have to stay in memory until the script ended.
Creating a variable instead of a constant, there is a good chance that the garbage collector will overwrite (or free) the memory after the variable is not longer needed.

A better way to protect sensitive data is to delete them immediately after using it:

```
$db_con = new stdClass();
$db_con->db_user = 'username';
$db_con->password = 'password';
$db_con->host = 'localhost';

$db_handler = new Database_Handler( $db_con );

$db_con = null;
```

After using the sensitive data, the assigning to `null` will overwrite the data in memory. An attacker have to get the memory dump just in the moment when `$db_con` contains the sensitive data. And that is a very short time in the example above (if the class Database_Handler do not save a copy of it).

Comment: This response does not directly address the question.  Any plugin author can have a field day with WordPress if they convince you to install their code and have malicious intent.   It is no different than willingly installing a virus on your system.   This argument to not move wp-config.php is pointless.  This is like saying that willfully installing a car bomb in your car makes setting the car alarm useless.  Technically true but WTF?!?

Comment: No, it is not pointless. The question is: Can I protect the database account by hiding the wp-config.php. And the answer is clearly: No.
It is the same as if you ask 'Can I protect my car against car bombs with a car alarm?'
There is no other benefit by hiding your wp-config as of protecting database access or ftp access. Both are in the global scope. I'm sure there are more ways for attackers to get access to global vars without injecting code.

Comment: I don't see "can I protect the database account by hiding the wp-config.php" in the original question.   The original question was "does it makes sense to move the wp-config.php".   The answer is absolutely yes, IMO.   It is like asking if you should lock your front door when you go out.   Saying "someone can easily break a window and get in anyway, so why bother" does not answer the fundamental point of the question.   IMO the question asked was this, "Is it worth the extra effort to move wp-config.php? ANY benefit doing so?".  Yes.  At the very least it keeps out the lazy hackers.

Comment: _One of the most common security best practices..._ You missed a very (very, very) important point: To what an attacker is interested? And it is *not* how do you styled your wp-config.php. An attacker is interessted in the values you defined in your wp-config. Grabbing your example with the front door: Hiding your wp-config is the same as if you will lock your front door, but store all your gold unprotected in the garden. All values defined in the wp-config are *globally* defined. So they are *all* accessible outside of wp-config. Even if you hide your wp-config, the values are still present.

Comment: I think those that argue in favor of moving it are trying to protect against scenarios where wp-config.php could be displayed in plain text via an HTTP request, rather than scenarios where it could be exposed to other PHP code running on the host.

Comment: @Ralf912 - that is not exactly accurate.   The global defines are ACCESSIBLE by all program files in all directories but not displayed.   In order to SEE the values you would need to be able to write modified code back to the server.  Whereas a mis-configured server with wp-config.php in doc root will readily display those values as plain text.  That is the underlying point.   Seeing the code for any of the plugins/themes causes no harm.

Comment: Really good point about how `define` globalizes whatever is being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump an old post but is there not just an obvious solution to all this. We know there is some security benefits from moving the wp-config.php file out of the wordpress route directory. Some would argue that the benefits are minimal others would not.

On the flip side there can be some drawbacks to moving the file out of it's default location such as breaking some plugins that do not have functionality to look for the wp-config.php file in other locations.

Most obvious thing to me is to create a secret-info.php file outside of the wordpress route directory which contains variables for all your usernames and passwords i.e.

**$userName = "user";**

**$databasePassword = "12345";**

Leave the wp-config.php file in the default wordpress route directory, remove the username and password values from wp-config.php but leave everything else. Then just simply reference the $userName and $databasePassword variable by requiring secret-info.php in wp-config.php i.e.

**require('PATH-TO-FILE/secret-info.php');**

Seems the obvious thing to do, am I missing something here ?

Comment: It's actually a really good thing to add an answer to an old question, [there's even a badge for it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer). [WPSE is meant to be a repository of knowledge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour), rather than a forum.

Answer (score -1):

Eternety later and wordpress still puts `wp-config.php` by default in its root directory accessable to the web without even adding .htaccess rules to prevent access to it. All the shared hosting which have a one click wordpress install most likely do the same. The result is that most of wordpress sites ae configured like that and I don't believe I ever heard anyone saying "my site was hacked because wp-config.php was on the root directory".

To use the information contained in the file you need an access to the DB server, probably by adding scripts to some app server which if you run a VPS means that if an attacker has such an ability it is "game over" for you in any case, and on shared hosting they probably isolate access to DB based on user therefor it is not a trivial thing to do even in that setting.

The result is that the wordpress 5.2+ health info will not give a suggestion to move the file, and never heard of a security plugin that does it.

So a long term practical info shows that it is theoretically better to do it, but it is mostly a security theater.

The real problem with moving `wp-config.php` to one directory above is that it essentialy prevents other wordpress from being installed in the same directory as the first one, something that many people do. The solution is to still have your `wp-config.php` in the default location but add to it code that loads the actual configuration from a different file which is located outside of the web root and probably named in a way which is not generic but site specific.

The problem with that is that many wordpress toturials do not even mention the possibility of having `wp-config.php` in another place, and people that will come after you will have a WTF moment trying to figure out how to follow instructions which asks them to add a`define` to the `wp-config.php` file

Answer (score -2):

Apart from the security benefits, it also allows you to keep your WordPress instance under version control while keeping the core WordPress files as a submodule/external. This is how Mark Jaquith has setup his WordPress-Skeleton project. See https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton#assumptions for details.

Comment: He has it setup in the document root, not outside of it, so it's not relevant to this question. The technique that the question asked about specifies that you move `wp-config.php` one directory above *the vhost's document root*, not just one directory above the WordPress installation folder. The whole point is to get it outside of the folder that can be read by HTTP requests.