# Hiding wp-config.php via .htaccess on an install installed in another directory?

Tags: htaccess

Say my wordpress install is here, example.com/wp/ but my .htaccess is in example.com, am I ok with

```
<Files wp-config.php>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

or do I need to specify a directory?

```
<Files /wp/wp-config.php>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: +1 for testing it with a text file (or similar file). I just tested it and my finding is provided below as an answer.

Comment: Frankly, this kind of protection is superfluous - rather than reel off the reasons here, I'll let someone else [put it better than I could](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58820/1685) (different technique, same reasoning).

Comment: @toscho I had tested it, both times I saw just a blank white screen, hadn't thought to just try it with a txt file like Pothi had suggested. Thanks to TheDeadMedic I'm not even going to bother with it any further, but I am curious as to why with my text file experiment I receive 403 forbidden, and  for wp-config I just get a white screen?

Comment: @Chuck I'd put the white screen issue as a separate question so that the answer to it may help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only** the first version works...

```
<Files wp-config.php>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

As per [the current documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files), in `<Files filename>`, the filename should include a filename, or a wild-card string, where ? matches any single character, and * matches any sequences of characters.

So, specifying path doesn't work.