# Moving wp-config.php up 2 levels

Tags: security

Is it possible to change a setting so that wp-config.php could be moved up two directory levels (instead of the default 1 level)? This would allow the core WP files to be moved from public_html to a subdirectory, while simultaneously allowing wp-config.php to be moved above public_html and thus not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a great example of how to accomplish this in the top answer for the question: [Is moving wp-config outside the web root really beneficial?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/is-moving-wp-config-outside-the-web-root-really-beneficial#answer-74972)

The section titled "**How to move wp-config.php to any location on your server**" provides the following solution:

> But what if you've moved [wp-config.php] somewhere else? Easy. Create a new wp-config.php in the WordPress directory with the following code:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> /** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
> if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
>     define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
>
> /** Location of your WordPress configuration. */
> require_once(ABSPATH . '../phpdocs/wp-config.php');
> ```
>
> (Be sure to change the above path to the actual path of your relocated wp-config.php file.)
>
> If you run into a problem with open_basedir, just add the new path to the open_basedir directive in your PHP configuration:
>
> ```
> open_basedir = "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/;/var/www/vhosts/example.com/phpdocs/;/tmp/"
> ```
>
> That's it!

Comment: Thanks Dave! Now, I just want to make sure I understand the path. If wp-config.php is in /root and Wordpress is in /root/public_html/blog then the path would be '../../wp-config.php' ? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes @Greg, that would be the correct path value for you're scenario.