# How secure is a wp-config file?

Tags: password, wp-config

Considering the information that is in the wp-config file, how secure is this file?  I have password salts in place, but can someone view this file?  Or to what level of difficulty can some view the contents?

Answer (score 3):

This is really more of a server configuration question. By necessity, `wp-config.php` must be readable by WordPress itself, but file access/security beyond that is really a matter of how your server is configured.

- [Refer to the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) for recommended file permissions for WordPress.
- [Refer to the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-config.php) for recommended ways to secure `wp-config.php`
- [Refer to this related WPSE question/answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/is-moving-wp-config-outside-the-web-root-really-beneficial/74972#74972) regarding moving `wp-config.php` out of the web root entirely

Comment: Ok, but can some view into my wp-config and see the password for my db?

Comment: There is no definitive answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

This could be hacked if for example a bad plugin is installed and creates flaws. This could be hacked because of the CRSF flaw that is to say a hacker utilizes an approved user account to make bad things.

You could start with this in .htaccess:

```
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

But there is not an absolute protection.