# Moving wp-config.php one level up - 500 error - Nginx

Tags: wp-config

My wordpress installation is at `/var/www/html/`

I have moved the wp-config.php file one level up to `/var/www/`

and deleted the original file. However, I am getting a 500 error.

Within the wp-config.php there is a line that read:

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

I have read that wordpress should automatically read the wp-config if it's only one directory up. I am also using Nginx. Not sure why there is a problem here.

The solution at this thread for specifying the path

[Is moving wp-config outside the web root really beneficial?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391)

didn't work. I have tried:

```
<?php

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Location of your WordPress configuration. */
require_once(ABSPATH . '../var/www/wp-config.php');
```

UPDATE:

I was able to retrieve the following troubleshooting information:

```
2018/10/29 18:54:09 [error] 10017#10017: *171699 FastCGI sent in stderr:
 "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/wp-config.php): failed to
 open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/wp-config.php on line 8

PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
 '/var/www/html/../wp-config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
 /var/www/html/wp-config.php on line 8" while reading response header from upstream,
```

In this instance I defined line 8 as `require_once(ABSPATH . '../wp-config.php');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is moving wp-config outside the web root really beneficial?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/is-moving-wp-config-outside-the-web-root-really-beneficial)

Comment: I have read that thread, but didn't fix the problem. I am only moving wp-config, one directory up which should be automatically detected according to codex

Comment: Do you still have a `wp-config.php` file in your WordPress site's root directory? If not, you might need to use `define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ . '/html/' );`, since your `wp-config.php` file isn't in the WP directory.

Comment: According to the other thread, I created a wp-config.php file and put the path to the new wp-config - but still I am getting a 500 error.

Comment: See my answer. tl;dr — I think your path is incorrect, and I offer a couple ways to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I assume the following, going by your question:

- Your WordPress site is at `/var/www/html`
- Your WordPress sites's full config file is at `/var/www/wp-config.php`
- There is a small file at `/var/www/html/wp-config.php` that (ideally) will load `/var/www/wp-config.php`
- Your `/var/www/wp-config.php` contains all the necessary content to run your WordPress site (ie, the code from `wp-config-sample.php`, updated as appropriate with your DB information, etc).
- There are no other WordPress installations in `/var/www/*`

Given all that, your `/var/www/html/wp-config.php` file should contain the following:

```
<?php

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Location of your WordPress configuration. */
require_once(ABSPATH . '../wp-config.php');
```

or

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Location of your WordPress configuration. */
require_once(ABSPATH . '/var/www/wp-config.php');
```

From your `/var/www/html` directory, the path `../var/www/wp-config.php` is looking for `/var/www/var/www/wp-config.php`, which presumably doesn't exist.

### Update

The error message: `failed to open stream: Permission denied` indicates that your webserver can't read the `/var/www/wp-config.php` file. It will at least need to read the file in order to open it.

I'd recommend asking your host to fix the permissions, or ask them how you can do it yourself. If you're self-hosting on a *nix VPS or something similar, you'll be looking for the `chown` and/or `chmod` commands.

Comment: Pat, all of your assumptions are correct however the problem persists. Please see updated question, with troubleshooting information

Comment: I've updated my answer. It looks like it's a permissions issue.

Comment: I have setup the server, but what would be the correct permissions to set? Currently the file outside the root is at 640, and the wp-config inside the root is 644.

Comment: In any case Wordpress should be able to read the file outside the root automatically, so I presume the permissions are a problem for the file outside the root ?

Comment: Yes, I'd say the permissions are the problem. If you're able to, try setting the permissions on `/var/www/wp-config.php` to `644`.

Comment: ok that does the trick - thanks so much. I suppose there won't be any security issues with that? Because wordpress recommends that wp-config permissions is set to 600

Comment: If you want to set the permissions to `600`, which is probably not the worst idea, you should set the file's owner to whatever ID the webserver runs as (probably something like `www-data`), but for that you'll probably need to check with your hosting provider.

Comment: great, I was able to change to www-data and set permissions to 600 and everything works as expected. thanks again