# How do I test to ensure that my wp-config file is protected?

Tags: htaccess, security, apache

Since `order allow,deny` is deprecated in 2.4 I wanted to rewrite the rules in my .htaccess file to use the new  rules. Previously I was using:

```
<files wp-config.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
```

Which I've rewritten to:

```
<FilesMatch "wp-config.php">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

**How do I confirm that my method is actually working?** I'm not certain how hackers might gain access to this file so I don't know how to test it.

Comment: What is this supposed to help against? If you can answer that, you can test it

Comment: To be honest, I'm not certain. My boss told me that it needed to be protected. The method using `Allow and Order` was written by someone else before I started working here. All I know is that hackers are able to (somehow) gain access to an unprotected file. I've tried researching how they do it, but I'm coming up with nothing.

Comment: This is not really WordPress specific, you might have better luck at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). As far as I understand this is done to, in case of misconfiguration of the server, keep the wp-config.php private. My personal opinion: if the server is misconfigured, why should .htaccess still work. So we don't do this, but have the file have CHMOD 0600 (-rw-------).

Answer (score 1):

The old method works for me, and any requests result in a 403 status response instead of execution of the php script.  I've not checked your 2nd method, but if it works it will similarly respond with 403 denied/forbidden.

To test you simply have to insert the URL of your "wp-config.php" in the address bar of your browser e.g. http://example.com/wp-config.php . Depending on browser and/or sites custom 403 settings your browser will display "forbidden", "access denied" etc.

Note you can also move wp-config.php **one** directory up from where Wordpress installed it - and if this is then above Webroot/public_html it will no longer be "directly" accessible by hackers. More on this here [Is moving wp-config outside the web root really beneficial?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/is-moving-wp-config-outside-the-web-root-really-beneficial)

Comment: The old method does not work in 2.4 and I prefer not to use deprecated methods. Also, it seems that wp-config.php file is not accessible through your browser. If you attempt that it the browser returns a blank page.

Comment: If you request `wp-config.php` and get a blank page (200 OK response) then that suggests the file **is accessible**, since that is the expected output of `wp-config.php`. The problem is that if there is a server misconfiguration that resulted in PHP files not to be processed by the PHP parser then the raw PHP code, including your DB connection credentials, will be sent as plain text to the client. That is the reason for blocking direct access. However, as scytale mentions, it would be preferable to move the `wp-config.php` file out of the public HTML webspace (if that is an option for you).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that by looking at my server's error logs I could see where the server denied permission to me when I attempted to visit http://example.com/wp-config.php

It looked like this:

> [Fri Nov 02 17:52:22.222222 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 222] [client 22.222.222.222:22222] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /nas/wp/www/sites/example/wp-config.php

Comment: Curious you are seeing an "error" state in your server's "error log"? This shouldn't trigger a "server error". If you are _blocked_ from accessing this file then you should see a 4xx response in the servers "access log" - this is an HTTP response, not a server error. (?)

Comment: It was in the Apache logs.